# class object initialization in c++

Tags: c++

Assuming the following class declaration :

```
class A { };
```

What is the difference between the following initialization ?

- `A * c = new A();`
- `A c;`
- `A()`

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: `case` statements are not capitalized and must have an accompanying `switch` block. Please fix your code

Comment: It depends. In case 2 *no* object is created, it's actually a function declaration.

Comment: @DigviJayPatil: in `case 2: ` it should be `A c` not `A c()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For case 1 the `A` object instance is created on the heap, while the location of the variable `c` depends on if it's a global, member or local variable.

<sub>[Note: Question edited, case 2 totally different]</sub>
<strike>For case 2 *no* object is created, as it is a function declaration.</strike>
For case 2, the location of `c` depends on *where* it's declared. If it's a global variable, then it's placed in the global data segment. If it's an argument or a local variable, it's placed on the stack, if it's a member variable it's placed wherever the containing object is placed.

In case 3 a temporary variable is created by the compiler wherever it wants, most likely the stack though.

---

It's important to note that the C specification actually doesn't specify *where* variables are actually placed, the specification only places constraints on the scope, life-time and linkage of variables, like arguments and local variables only being available inside the function (or nested block) they were declared in.

Comment: Caution, OP just changed case 2.